# Statistics of user purchasing platforms and amounts

Tags: sql

I have a table that records user spending on an online shopping website that has both desktop and mobile applications.（I'm learning PieCloudDB Database) I want to find out the number of users and their total spend per day who are mobile only, desktop only, and both desktop and mobile.

| user_id | date | platform | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-01 | mobile | 27.99 |
| 1 | 2023-12-01 | desktop | 32.68 |
| 1 | 2023-12-02 | desktop | 19.90 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | mobile | 83.46 |
| 2 | 2023-12-02 | mobile | 43.96 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 | desktop | 22.00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 | mobile | 63.48 |
| 3 | 2023-12-03 | mobile | 28.28 |

Results should be:

| date | platform | total_amount | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-01 | desktop | 22 | 1 |
| 2023-12-01 | mobile | 83.46 | 1 |
| 2023-12-01 | both | 60.67 | 1 |
| 2023-12-02 | desktop | 19.9 | 1 |
| 2023-12-02 | mobile | 107.44 | 2 |
| 2023-12-02 | both | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-03 | desktop | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-03 | mobile | 28.28 | 1 |
| 2023-12-03 | both | 0 | 0 |

I can't think of a solution to this problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried to group by on `date` and `platform` then `sum` the`amount` and `count` the `user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using multiple select to obtain statistics per day and platform using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, then apply `CROSS JOIN` On distinct platforms to get the desired output :

```
with cte as (
  select date, platform, sum(total_amount) as total_amount,
                         count(total_users) as total_users
  from (
    select date, max(platform) as platform, sum(amount) as total_amount, count(distinct user_id) as total_users
    from mytable
    group by user_id, date
    having min(platform) = 'mobile' and max(platform) = 'mobile'
  union all 
    select date, max(platform) as platform, sum(amount) as total_amount, count(distinct user_id) as total_users
    from mytable
    group by user_id, date
    having min(platform) = 'desktop' and max(platform) = 'desktop'
  union all
    select date, 'both' as platform, sum(amount) as total_amount, count(distinct user_id) as total_users
    from mytable
    group by user_id, date
    having count(case when platform = 'desktop' then 1 end) + count(case when platform = 'mobile' then 1 end) = count(*)
       and count(case when platform = 'desktop' then 1 end) >= 1
       and count(case when platform = 'mobile' then 1 end) >= 1
  ) as s
  group by date, platform
),
dates as (
  select distinct date from mytable
),
platforms as (
  select 'mobile' as platform union all
  select 'desktop' union all
  select 'both'
)
select d.date, p.platform, coalesce(c.total_amount, 0) as total_amount, coalesce(c.total_users, 0) as total_users
from dates d
cross join platforms p
left join cte c on c.date = d.date and c.platform = p.platform
order by d.date, total_amount;
```

Results :

```
date        platform    total_amount    total_users
2023-12-01  desktop     22.00           1
2023-12-01  both        60.67           1
2023-12-01  mobile      83.46           1
2023-12-02  both        0               0
2023-12-02  desktop     19.90           1
2023-12-02  mobile      107.44          2
2023-12-03  both        0               0
2023-12-03  desktop     0               0
2023-12-03  mobile      28.28           1
```

[Demo on postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ks6B2AHP)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that PieCloud support PostgreSQL.
You need to generate value for Platform if there are users who spent via both the platforms.

You can achieve the desired result using - Generated values using `CTE`, `WINDOW function` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
WITH ALL_PLATFORMS(PLATFORM) 
 AS (SELECT 'mobile' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'desktop' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'both'),
ALL_DATES(DATE) 
 AS (SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM YOUR_TABLE),
SEGRAGATED_DATA 
 AS (SELECT T.*,
            COUNT(DISTINCT PLATFORM) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID,DATE) AS CNT
       FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
-- 
SELECT D.DATE, P.PLATFORM, 
       SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS TOTAL_USERS
  FROM ALL_PLATFORMS P
CROSS JOIN ALL_DATES D
LEFT JOIN SEGRAGATED_DATA S 
  ON S.DATE = D.DATE AND S.USER_ID = T.USER_ID
 AND ((S.CNT = 1 AND P.PLATFORM = S.PLATFORM)
      OR (S.CNT > 1 AND P.PLATFORM = 'both'))
GROUP BY D.DATE, P.PLATFORM
ORDER BY D.DATE, P.PLATFORM
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried it and I got the error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t" (SQLSTATE 42P01).

Comment: Yes, one comma was missing before `SEGRAGATED_DATA` in WITH clause. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following query in PostgreSQL(PieCloudDB should be compatible with PostgreSQL), I got the results you expected.

```
with temp as (
    select date, platform
    from (
        select distinct date 
        from your_table ) as d
    cross join (
        select 'desktop' as platform union all
        select 'mobile' union all
        select 'both') as p
)

select t.date, t.platform, 
       COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as total_amount, 
       COALESCE(count(distinct user_id),0) as total_users
from (
    select *,
           case when plat_num=2 then 'both' else platform end as plat_type
    from (
        select *,
               count(platform) over(partition by user_id, date) as plat_num
        from your_table 
        ) as t1 
    ) as t2
right join temp as t
on t2.date = t.date and t2.plat_type = t.platform
group by t.date, t.platform
```